# What is the different between change and to change?

Tags: american-english, jokes

I have just question about what is the difference between change and change to?

In [this comic](http://m.9gag.com/gag/aMbNvEP) there are two sentences:

1. Who wants change?
2. Who wants to change?

I'm not sure what the difference between them. Please let me know more English and rephrase this.

Comment: You should add the relevant details from the website to your question rather than just putting a link. As it is, one could only provide some definitions of "change" without context.

Comment: @user3169 The link is a comic that would be difficult to excerpt as context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The link refers to a comic strip with a public speaker saying each line in turn.

In the first line, "change" is a noun, and it means something new, presumably in a political sense.

> Who wants change?
>   Who wants *politics to be different than their current state*?

In the second line, "to change" is an infinitive verb, and it means to become different, or more specifically here, for a person to alter his or her own pattern of behavior.

> Who wants to change?
>   Who wants *to alter their own way of living?*?

In short, we all want things to be different, but nobody wants to adapt to make that happen.